# Playing E Aeolian over B Aeolian progression?

Tags: guitar, harmony, modes

I have this simple Bm G F#m Bm / Bm G F#7 Bm chord progression. AFAIK, that means I'm in B Aeolian (in the key of D major) - plus that F#7 dominant chord that would put me briefly in B harmonic minor? For some reason I started noodling around in E Aeolian over the loop and many of the notes sound right. Is there any particular reason this happens? I'd like to understand the trick to incorporate it into my playing.

Comment: B Aeolian and B harmonic minor aren't keys. B minor is a key. A V7 chord is often used in minor keys because of the strong V7-I relationship. The harmonic minor scale does acknowledge the V7 chord. As you noted, D is the relative major for B minor. E Dorian and E Aeolian only differ in one note(C# vs C), explaining why "many of the notes sound right".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're firmly in B minor, basically meaning there's a B note and a D note. B minor has several incarnations, harmonic, natural, melodic, Dorian to name a few. All have subtly different notes, which can crop up almost anywhere in a piece in B minor.

The notes contained in any of the scales in B that are mentioned here will vary by only one note from those of E. B Aeolian has B C# D E F# G A.  E Aeolian has E F# G A B C D. C/C# is the only difference. If you happened not to play either while noodling, you have exactly the same set.

Check out how notes differ round the circle of fifths - each neighbour has one note different.

Incidentally, B *minor* is a *key*, B *Aeolian*, *harmonic*, *Dorian* are all sets of notes, known as scales or modes, but not as separate *keys*.